# U need to POST a request in JSON format using OKHTTP3 - Android

Tags: android

I have an Electricity recharge activity on my android studio and it has 2 `TextInputEditText` fields, 1 for entering a meter # and the other one for entering the recharge amount and a SUBMIT button.

When a user enters the required meter number and the amount to be recharged, & presses the SUBMIT button, I wan the requests should be POSTED in JSON format and I get the account confirmation details.

I have tried that using the code below but it is not working. I cannot connect to the server, let alone POST the request. Where am I getting it wrong in my code?

```
       package googleplayservices.samples.android.com.whitney.shumba;

       import android.content.ContentValues;
       import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
       import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.TextView;

       import org.json.JSONException;
       import org.json.JSONObject;

       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.util.HashMap;

       import okhttp3.Call;
       import okhttp3.Callback;
       import okhttp3.MediaType;
       import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
       import okhttp3.Request;
       import okhttp3.RequestBody;
       import okhttp3.Response;

    public class Zesa extends AppCompatActivity {
       private TextInputEditText txtinputmeter, txtinputamount;
       private Button submit;
       private TextView json;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zesa);

    json = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonTV);
    txtinputmeter = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_input_meter);
    txtinputamount = (TextInputEditText) 
      findViewById(R.id.txt_input_amount);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
       submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf- 
            8");
            ContentValues params = null;
            params.put("txtinputmeter", "37132137516");
            params.put("txtinputamount", "$5.00");
            JSONObject parameter = null;
            try {
                parameter = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(params));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            String url = "http://52.8.97.52/zesa";

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, 
                 parameter.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; 
            charset=utf-8")
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.e("response", call.request().body().toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws 
                     IOException {
                    Log.e("response", response.body().string());
                }


            });

            Submit();
        }

        private void Submit() {
        }

               });

              };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define **application/json** only in **Mediatype**. Remove header from request.

You can post call using okhttp3 like,

```
try {

        MediaType JSOMediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSOMediaType, data);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(myurl)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```